# Adding schedule job to nodejs microservicse best practice

Tags: node.js, microservices

We are using microservicse approach in our backend

We have a nodejs service which provide a REST endpoint that grap some data from mongodb and apply some business logic to it.

We would need to add a schedule job every 15 min to sync the mongodb data with some 3rd party data source.

The question here is - dose adding to this microservicse a schedule job that would do that, consider anti pattern?

I was thinking from the other point of having a service that just do the sync job will create some over engineering for simple thing, another repo, build cycle deployment etc hardware, complicated maintenance etc

Would love to hear more thoughts around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an AWS CloudWatch event rule to schedule CloudWatch to generate an event every 15 minutes.  Make a Lambda function a target of the CloudWatch event so it executes every 15 minutes to sync your data.  Be aware of the VPC/NAT issues if calling your 3rd party resources from Lambda if they are external to your VPC/account.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, if it is like an ETL job, you can offload it to a [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) function (if you are using AWS) or a serverless function to do the same.
Also, look into [MongoDB Stitch](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch) that can do something similar.

Comment: True, the case is that for now we are not using AWS, just our own infrastructure, but I guess anyway your suggestion is to separate the two?

Comment: Yes, ideally you would keep the business logic and ETL job separate. 
You would not want your application server to be busy processing ETL jobs, which may run for a long time, in turn affecting the performance of the app itself.

That said if you think maintenance is an issue, see if you can deploy them both off of a single code repository. It is a good way to manage a single repository with many services for microservices. [Here](https://medium.com/@somakdas/code-repository-for-micro-services-mono-repository-or-multiple-repositories-d9ad6a8f6e0e) is a good article on the same